# Nested API View of Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

At the moment I developed the following code, for me to get the Contact List of each user. The views return the ID numbers of the Contacts of the User. I need to get, instead of the ID numbers, the 'name' and 'last_name' attribute of said contacts. I am quite new to Django's REST Framework and I'm not quite sure what to do next but I believe I have to nest the APIView. I would really appreciate some help!

views.py

```
def list_contacts(request, id_profile):
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('api_users:contact_list', kwargs={'pk':id_profile}))
    response = requests.get(url)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=id_profile)
    if response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK:
        data = response.content
        user = json.loads(data)
        return render(request, 'profiles/contact_list.html', {'user':user})
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profiles/%Y/%m/%d', blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, default='null')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name+' '+self.last_name

    def active_profiles():
        return Profile.objects.filter(active=True)
```

api/views.py

```
class ContactListView(generics.ListAPIView):

queryset = Profile.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserContactListSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
search_fields = ('name', 'last_name',)

def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    contacts = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serializer = UserContactListSerializer(contacts)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

api/serializers.py

```
class UserContactListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name','last_name','contacts']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is going on in your `list_contacts` but if you want to use the same serializer as a field in itself, you currently can't.
While Django models allow you to use `'self'` as the reference, DRF doesn't.

What you can instead do is create another serializer and use that as the field.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name")

class UserContactListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     contacts = UserSerializer(many=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Profile
         fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "contacts")
```

Comment: wow. That was nice! Thanks! I just have another little question. When I show the result of the whole API it shows: {'NAME':'John','LAST_NAME':'Doe'} Do you know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Nvm. Solved it by adding {{user.contact.name}}